# Realm usage when a APP receives a background event and the iPhone is locked

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, realm-js

So I'm developing an APP in react-native that receives a background event. And when the background event is received the APP crash and doesn't save Data on the realm library when the phone is locked.

Is geolocation Based APP, so it needs to save the information when the phone is locked (when you press the block button on the iPhone).

Tried to modify some native objective-c code, only worked on DEV builds (debug build) but not in Production build.

Code on the Native Code

```
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];

// Get our Realm file's parent directory
NSString *folderPath = realm.configuration.fileURL.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent.path;

// Disable file protection for this directory
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:@{NSFileProtectionKey: NSFileProtectionNone}
                                 ofItemAtPath:folderPath error:nil];
```

Realm save the data when the phone is locked.

Comment: A little bit more context about your problem would help better understand it, like what do you mean by phone is blocked? and in which delegate method are you trying to save the data? is your application a VOIP application?

Comment: thanks for the help

Comment: Blocked == locked ?

Comment: @MatthewLuiHK Yes

Comment: as i remember, realm has a doc claimed that they lose the ability to access the file when phone is locked due to disk encryption, please search for the doc. If so, you can temporally store the info into UserDefault and do the write action later

Comment: They only have it on the Objective-c doc, not in the React-Native doc. Do you know some doc to save the info on UserDefault? Thanks for the tip.

Comment: For RN, there is a UserDefault thing, again just as I remember, just search whole RN doc with persistence keywork